# Asking questions about disabled travel and immigration

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I'm disabled, on wheelchair, I would like to ask 2 questions, one about visiting a country, another about immigrating. Is it okay or would they be closed as off topic?

It's about requirements and whether disabled get rejected and stuff like that.

Comment: I asked the same question on Meta.travel.se, waiting for answers, checking the scope of both sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would depend on the nature of the question. Questions, like "which method of travel are suitable for disabled persons" or "can I use my blue badge in another EU state for parking purposes" probably belong to Travel.SE for example.

However questions like "what obstacles are in getting long term visas while disabled", or "how can I extend my blue badge after I move to another EU country" is definitely more suited to this site.